# Azure SQL BACPAC import Failed

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have created a SQL Server in Azure and now I'm trying to import a database from a BACPAC file. After about 10 minutes, the Azure portal logs to the import/export history:

> An unexpected error was returned by the SQL engine while preparing the operation inputs. Error: 40532, State: 1.

What can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: *40532: Cannot open server "%.*ls" requested by the login. The login failed.* Check a login which you use to connect.

Comment: I was using this guide to import the bacpac  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell (chapter Using Azure Portal). I was already logged in since I was within the Azure Portal

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, May you say me what do you mean? I'm using Azure portal what kind of login I should check?